# How to access CouchDB installed on another machine?

Tags: c#-4.0, couchdb

We have CouchDB installed on a separate machine.
When it was installed on my machine, it was accessible through Fauxton via link http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html

Also, I am using Divan, a C# library to interact with CouchDB. It uses host as localhost and port as 5984 - default host and port names to connect with database.

But now I have CouchDB installed on another machine, how can I access it in this case?
Please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to allow exterior access in the new machine (which I'll just call the server). Your computer is the client. First, make sure the server is accessible from your network and get its IP address using `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` in the command line.

First, in the server, open the CouchDB configuration file, which is

`/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini` in Linux
or
`C:\Program Files\CouchDB\etc\couchdb\local.ini` in Windows

and change

`[httpd]
bind_address = 127.0.0.1`

to

`[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0`

If there is no bind_address already in the file, just add it.

Then save the file.

Now, from the client, you can access futon from your machine using `{SERVER_IP}:5984/_utils`.

In Divan, set `host` to `{SERVER_IP}`. Unless you configure it otherwise, the port remains 5984.

Reference:

- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/intro.html *
- http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/http.html *

(*) I'm assuming you're using CouchDB 2.0, but in my experience with 1.6.1 this instructions also work.

Comment: latest path is `/opt/couchdb` https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/intro.html

Comment: I've it installed on windows 7, and here is the path in case anyone needs it: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb`

I have 2 files here, local.ini and default.ini, just changing local.ini and restarting the service did not work for me, but changing both.ini file works :) GL and HF.

Addtional info of my system: `Windows 7 x64, CouchDB 1.6.1_R16B02`

Answer (score 5):

Connect to your server locally:

```
localhost:5984/_utils
```

then simply from the setting section, change the bind_address to 0.0.0.0

[image]

Comment: I did the same and now i am not able to access the gui.